# How to use a python zipapp as a kernel in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, zipapp

I have a **python env made with a zip app**  [shiv](https://github.com/linkedin/shiv) and want to use it for my **Jupyter Notebook**.
I saw a lot of solution with virtual-env, but nothing with a zip app. I tried to create a custom kernel with `python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=myenv.pyz`, but when I use it, I still can't import my customs lib. Any idea how I can do that ?

I know that the choice of a *.pyz* for an env isn't a good solution, but I can't change this part of the process.